# How can I build two interactive web-sites from one GNU makefile and mostly the same source?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I'm using GNU Make to build a dynamic web site but I need to build two versions. As a net result currently I run my makefile using two command line incantations. This is inefficient and can result in errors (I don't always remember to run both versions or make a typing error and they fail) thus I want to make it one build.

The Command Line incantations are:

```
sudo make release build=test
sudo make release build=release
```

The two incantations activate ifeq blocks that set the path and modify some files.
Part of the much simplified (to help readability) top level makefile:

```
subs = today tomorrow
files = index.php foot.php

ifeq ($(build),test)
export path = /var/www/html/cgi-test
$(shell cp -f head-test.php head.php)
$(shell sed -i '/"DB"/c\  define("DB", "db_test");' subs.php)
else ifeq ($(build),release)
export path = /var/www/html/cgi-new
$(shell cp -f head-release.php head.php)
$(shell sed -i '/"DB"/c\  define("DB", "db_new");' subs.php)
endif

.PHONY: all go       

all:
    $(MAKE) go
    @for ALL in $(subs);\
        do $(MAKE) -C $$ALL all || exit $$?;\
    done;

go:
    cp $(files) $(path)/.
```

The sub-makefiles have a very similar structure but don't need the ifeq blocks because the files and paths have already been setup.

I think I can simply move the shell commands into the .PHONY rules but I can't do that with the exports because I get errors "export: : bad variable name".

I could do it with a batch file and call the makefile twice but that sidesteps the problem rather than cures it and I wish to learn from the process.

So can anybody show me the way to do this in a makefile?

Thanks to Tripleee here is the answer that finally worked back ported to match my starting post. The one major change is that I have gone back to 'all' as the rule I expect to start the build habits die hard! - Thanks

```
.PHONY: all both rel-test rel-release

cgi-test := cgi-test
db-test := db_test

cgi-release := cgi-new
db-release := db_new

subs = today tomorrow
files = index.php foot.php

all: both

both: rel-test rel-release

rel-test rel-release: rel-%:
    cp -f head-$*.php head.php
    sed -i '/"DB"/c\  define("DB", "$(db-$*)");' subs.php
    $(MAKE) go path=/var/www/html/strutts/$(cgi-$*)
    @for ALL in $(subs);\
      do $(MAKE) build=$* path=/var/www/html/strutts/$(cgi-$*) -C $$ALL all || exit $$?;\
    done;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
.PHONY: both rel-test rel-release
both: rel-test rel-release

cgi-test := cgi-test
db-test := db_test

cgi-release := cgi-new
db-release := db_new

rel-%:
    cp -f head-$*.php head.php
    sed -i '/"DB"/c\    define("DB", "$(db-$*)")' subs.php
    $(MAKE) release build=$* path=/var/www/html/$(cgi-$*)
```

The reason the `export` can't be moved into a recipe is that you are using the `export` command of `make` itself, not the shell's command with the same name.

You absolutely should not use `sudo` unless you specifically require the output files to be owned and only writable by `root`. Even then, running as much as possible as a regular user would be proper hygiene; maybe add a `sudo` command inside the `Makefile` to copy the files to their final location.

Comment: OK I get "Nothing to be done for 'both'" so I moved the two "rel-test" and "rel-release" to be inside `$(MAKE) rel-test` & `$(MAKE) rel-release` below the 'both:' fixed that but now I have "Nothing to be done for 'rel-test' " and of course the "rel-release" so part way still trying!

Comment: You can't have transcrbed this correctly; you can't get "nothing to be done" for a `.PHONY` target.

Comment: I agree however, I have just cut and paste your code from above, fixed the tab problem and go `make both` and I get "make: Nothing to be done for 'both'.", not the error I expected at $(MAKE) release b..... If I then do as I said above I get past that and get the result described above.

Comment: If I do `make -v` I get `GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

Comment: If I do `make both --debug` and pick out the pertinent bit make clearly says it's done it and then it has not???  
Reading makefiles...  
Updating makefiles....  
Updating goal targets....  
 File 'rel-test' does not exist.  
Must remake target 'rel-test'.  
Successfully remade target file 'rel-test'.  
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/***/1and1/eleven/cgi'  
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'rel-test'.  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/***/1and1/eleven/cgi'  
I don't understand!

Comment: I'm guessing your full-blown `Makefile` has some generic rule which interferes with the parts you show.

Comment: The makefile is just as you posted nothing else.

Comment: `.PHONY: both rel-test rel-release

cgi-test := cgi-test
db-test := db_test

cgi-release := cgi-new
db-release := db_new

rel-%:
 cp -f head-$*.php head.php
 sed -i '/"DB"/c\    define("DB", "$(db-$*)")' subs.php
 $(MAKE) release build=$* path=/var/www/html/$(cgi-$*)

release:
 echo "In release"

both: rel-test rel-release`  Edit: Sorry just a mess of words the double space markdown is not working

Comment: I have a fixed version at https://ideone.com/OhPKb3 but I'll need to investigate more tomorrow about exactly why those changes are needed. I think the crucial fix is the explicit dependency `rel-test rel-release: rel-%`